# Finding weak_ptrs referring to a shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, weak-ptr

Is there a way to find out the number of weak_ptrs a shared_ptr is being referred by?

unique()/use_count() could be used for finding the shared_ptrs but is there a similar construct for finding the referring weak_ptrs.

I want to release the resource held by the shared_ptr only if there are no weak_ptrs referring to it. So that sometime in future if I try creating a shared_ptr from this weak_ptr, I shouldn't end up with a nullptr.

Is this possible currently in C++11?

Comment: If you have to do this I would re-examine your design

Comment: "I want to release the resource held by the shared_ptr only if there are no weak_ptrs referring to it."  Then why not use shared_ptr everywhere?

Comment: He is technically on a wrong path but the question is fair, what's the reasons for downvotes ?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### No.

There is no interface for doing this thing, because it would miss the entire point.

The resource is released if no `std::shared_ptr` refers to it.

By using `std::weak_ptr` you specifically allow your resource to be released. Don't use it if that's not what you want.

Comment: The resource is _destructed_ when the last `shared_ptr` is destructed, but it might be not deallocated in some cases. For example, if the resource was allocated with `std::make_shared`, some implementation could group together the control block and the memory for the allocated object. In this case, if you have weak_ptrs around, the memory would leak anyway, even if the resource is logically destructed. So, even if the motivation is wrong, the need to know how many weak_ptrs are around is legitimate and could be useful for debug purposes

Comment: @gigabytes While true, it's an implementation detail and it's not really relevant for the *program* using `std::weak_ptr`. Requiring the interface to be aware of the count would reveal too many implementation details and would restrict the other valid implementations. IMHO it's not really useful for debugging, since in the situation you mention, I would rather have a list of weak pointers pointing to the same control block. The count only tells you how many others you have to find. If you want to query the implementation detail, use the tools implementation provides you (as in, the debugger).

Comment: It's not an implementation detail since the standard allows that optimization and that's exactly the primary motivation of std::make_shared. Anyway, I'm not arguing that the standard should provide a way to query the number of weak_ptr still alive.